# Retain values in dialog box after closing - windows forms c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, dialog

I'm relatively new to C# and Windows forms so excuse me for what may seem like an easy question.

I have a windows application which has a dialog box which when opened contains textboxes with some default values.  These can be changed depending on what the user wants to use.  The values in this dialog box together with the content on the main form are then used to create an XML file.  The issue I have is if I go to open the dialog box again to change any values in the same session, the original values are there and not any of the new values.

How do I get it to keep the values that have been changed in that particular session?

Comment: I'm not sur I understood what you want to do, do you want to keep the values that were changed by the user the first time he opened the dialog box?

Comment: For a question like this, you really **must** attach your code.  We can't read minds, even here on SO.

Comment: Are you creating a new instance of your dialog every time you display it?

Comment: makes zero sense to ask the OP any question without seeing any code one would only be making an educated guess

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the values that were changed by the user the first time he opened the dialog box.  I don't have the code with me as I am at home, thought I would ask to get some clues as it is bugging me!

Comment: Why would you need to see code before supplying an answer when the question is so obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the user's values the next time you open the dialog box, you'll need to save those values somewhere, and then re-load them the next time the dialog is displayed (usually on Form_Load or Form_Show). And of course you'll need to save the values (probably in Form_Close?) before exiting.

Where you save those values is up to you. You can save them in some static variables in the form class if you want it to be just for that run of the program. Or you can store in a configuration file, the registry, isolated storage, etc. if you want to re-load those settings the next time the program is run.

Comment: Thanks for you help,  I've saved the values in a public static string in the form closing event and then reloaded the values in the form load.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly it sounds like you need to make use of background variables and TextChanged events (although I prefer KeyDown events and my code uses that instead). For instance, let's call your textbox TextBox1. You can then make a global variable called string Temp and use it like this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    temp = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Once your dialog box is closed you can use that variable elsewhere, in your case it sounds like you want to send it to an XML.
Another option is to use the keydown event to have a temporary XML file that retains the value of your text. This is obviously more computationally expensive but it's not really that big of a deal unless this is going to be used in a processor limited environment.
The last thing I'd mention is that you may run into trouble if you're using multi-threading and passing the value of that temp value. Look into using variables on other threads than you started with for help with that.

Comment: And what do you do when the user presses Cancel rather than Ok? You'd overwrite the old settings that the user elected to preserve. It's easier to just gather the settings from the dialog when the user presses Ok. It takes much less processing, is easier to code, and won't break when the user presses Cancel.

Comment: I agree if the dialog box has to be closed before using other aspects of the program but that isn't always the case. You can use the OK button to commit the changes if that is what you need, but in my personal experience I use textbox in tandem with other active controls in my program and that is why I use the keydown event. But to each their own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the values the user entered the last time he used your dialog, you need to keep a reference to your dialog somewhere.

Also if you set some data in your dialog on the Load event it might erase the data previously entered by the user. Without seeing your code I can't tell more at this point.